# No matching function for call to'DS3231 (const uint8_t &, const uint8_t &)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, lcd, servo, keypad

This was supposed to be the code for automatic pet feeder
Got it from here[1](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/automatic-pet-feeder-using-arduino)

The problem is that I always got a "No matching function for call to'DS3231 (const uint8_t &, const uint8_t &)"

Here's the error code

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"





















ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT:53:18: error: no matching function for call to 'DS3231::DS3231(const uint8_t&, const uint8_t&)'

 DS3231 rtc(A4, A5);

                  ^

In file included from C:\Users\SERIES\Desktop\ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT\ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT.ino:1:0:

D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:67:3: note: candidate: DS3231::DS3231(TwoWire&)

   DS3231(TwoWire & w);

   ^~~~~~

D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:67:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided

D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:66:3: note: candidate: DS3231::DS3231()

   DS3231();

   ^~~~~~

D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:66:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided

D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:62:7: note: candidate: constexpr DS3231::DS3231(const DS3231&)

 class DS3231 {

       ^~~~~~

D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:62:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided

D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:62:7: note: candidate: constexpr DS3231::DS3231(DS3231&&)

D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS3231/DS3231.h:62:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided

C:\Users\SERIES\Desktop\ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT\ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT.ino: In function 'void setup()':

ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT:84:7: error: 'class DS3231' has no member named 'begin'

   rtc.begin();

       ^~~~~

C:\Users\SERIES\Desktop\ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT\ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT.ino: In function 'void loop()':

ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT:130:10: error: 'class DS3231' has no member named 'getTimeStr'; did you mean 'getMinute'?

  t = rtc.getTimeStr();

          ^~~~~~~~~~

          getMinute

ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT:146:16: error: 'class DS3231' has no member named 'getTimeStr'; did you mean 'getMinute'?

  lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());

                ^~~~~~~~~~

                getMinute

ANA_FEEDER_PROJECT:152:16: error: 'class DS3231' has no member named 'getDateStr'; did you mean 'getDate'?

  lcd.print(rtc.getDateStr());

                ^~~~~~~~~~

                getDate

exit status 1

no matching function for call to 'DS3231::DS3231(const uint8_t&, const uint8_t&)'



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

The problem is that I always got a "No matching function for call to'DS3231 (const uint8_t &, const uint8_t &)"

Here's the error code

Comment: please read what you wrote ... there is no reason to repeat sentences

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong DS3231 library. Unfortunately, you can often find incompatible libraries that share the same name. The sketch you downloaded has been written for a specific version of the DS3231 library. Thus your choices are:

- either you use that specific version (linked to in the page you gave as reference)
- or you adapt the code to work with the version you have installed.